# Laravel validation date2 not bigger than the year of date1

Tags: laravel, validation

I am looking for an solution for a (custom) Validation Rule, that depends on an other array value.

Simplified it looks like this (using livewire):

```
...
'positions.*.date_from'             => 'required|date',
'positions.*.date_to'               => ['required','date','after_or_equal:positions.*.date_from'],
...
```

I now want to add a validation that `date_to` must not be next year from `date_from`. something like `before_or_equal:positions.*.date_from->endOfYear()`
or
`same_year_as:positions.*.date_from`

How can I make a custom data aware rule with arrays? The docs don't show any examples with that.

Since this case is in a livewire component, a possible workaround would be, that I set an additional array value `positions.*.max_year` on update of `date_from`, but this feels "dirty", and I would be interested in how to make such a rule.

Comment: If you want to add custom validation you can do that with in the Request class files. 

Example:

`
/**
     * Configure the validator instance.
     *
     * @param  Validator  $validator
     * @return void
     */
    public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
            // Checking if invalid.
            if (!$isValid) {
                $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Date cannot be greater than a year.');
            }
        }
   }
`

Comment: A simple solution is to not use `.*.` wildcards; loop over your `positions` and construct each rule as `positions.0.date_to` that checks `after_or_equal:positions.0.date_from` (and same for 1, 2, 3, etc., until you've constructed a Rule for each Index). No Custom Rule required either 